# Copy from one sheet to another sheet under a specific condition

Tags: vba, excel

I need to copy a selection from "sheet1" to an other sheet "sheet2" under a cell that contains a specific date in VBA but it break each time i want to run the procdurem if someone has an aswer to give me it will be very helpful

my procedure :

```
Dim n As Date:
Dim c As Range:
Dim cellule As Range:

n = ws.Range("E3").Value      ''this is the critera i need 
ws.Range("B3:B6").Copy      '' this is the selection i need

For Each c In ws2.Range("B1:D1")     ''' the criteria is in this selection
    If c.Value = n Then
        cellule = c.Offset(3, 0).Address     ''' this does not work

        ws2.Range(cellule).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone
Exit For
    End If
    Next
```

Or if you think of something else let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `cellule` as a Range, but Address is a property of a range, and a string. You could instead do as follows.

```
Dim n As Date
Dim c As Range
Dim cellule As Range

n = ws.Range("E3").Value      ''this is the critera i need

For Each c In ws2.Range("B1:D1")     ''' the criteria is in this selection
    If c.Value = n Then
        ws.Range("B3:B6").Copy
        c.Offset(3, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone
        Exit For
    End If
Next c
```